# Check if author or current user has posts published

Tags: custom-post-types, author

I'm doing a QUIZ system, but I'm facing a problem that I dont know how to fix it.

I need to make a `if` basically, where it will check if the current user has a post published, as the question title. It's important to say that the **posts** are a specifically **custom-post-type**, so I need to check if there is a post with a certain post-type with the author-id equal to the current user ID.

Can someone help-me?

Comment: Glad I could help! And sorry about the echo, I tested it using error_log and then forgot to take out the brackets. Could you maybe change the question title to 'Check if author or current user has posts published' or something that's more easy to find in search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using get_posts or WP_query with similar $args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'author'     => get_current_user_id(),
);

$wp_posts = get_posts($args);

if (count($wp_posts)) {
    echo "Yes, the current user has 'your_custom_post_type' posts published!";
} else {
    echo "No, the current user does not have 'your_custom_post_type' posts published.";
}
```

Comment: It's perfect @dalv, it worked really nice, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

diving into this I found that `count_user_posts()` is a better solution. it's shorter, and also cheaper in resources than `get_posts()`;

so here it is:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); //the logged in user's id
$post_type = 'your-post-type-here';
$posts = count_user_posts( $user_id, $post_type ); //cout user's posts
if( $posts > 0 ){
  //user has posts
}
```

Comment: Do you use that by itself or does it integrate with the previous answer?

Comment: by iteself. but now i see i've missed something, let me edit.